# How to parse a forward slash from command line in java?

Tags: java, parsing, command-line

I need to input a date in the command line e.g.

```
java PrintCalendar 24/5/2020
```

However, I am only able to parse the date if I input it like this:

```
java PrintCalendar 24 5 2020.
```

I want to be able to parse both the integers, and the "/" in between the integers.

*I CAN'T USE A PRE-DEFINED DATE CLASS*

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int theDay = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String s = args[1];
    int month = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);  
    String s2 = args[3];
    int year = Integer.parseInt(args[4]); 

    System.out.println(theDay + s + month + s2 + year);

    }  
}
```

Comment: use the `String#split`method, or for a further level, use a date fromatter in order to parse a string date in a given format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing each part of the date string, parse the complete string, `args[0]` e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(args[0], formatter);
            System.out.println(date);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pass date string argument as dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Run it with the argument, `24/5/2020`

**Output:**

```
2020-05-24
```

**[Update]**

Posting this update because OP can not use date/time API.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            String[] dateParts = args[0].split("/");
            int theDay = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);

            System.out.println("Day: " + theDay + ", Month: " + month + ", Year: " + year);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pass date string argument as dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Day: 24, Month: 5, Year: 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
int theDay=0, month=0, year=0;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(args[0], "/");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            theDay = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            month = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());  
            year = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        }

        System.out.println(theDay + " " + month + " " + year);
```

> Basically the StringTokenizer (String str, String delim) split the
>   input string into multiple tokens. It splits It depending on the delim
>   String. For exampl StringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer ("This is
>   a-string", "- ") will result in splitting str into tokens every time a
>   "-" or a " "(whitespace) is found. So the tokens are: "This" "is" "a"
>   "string"

More information about the StringTokenizer class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @Noods Yes I edited and corrected the answer. It should work now. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `args` length greater than one which means that the input without slash and build the `split[]`

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int theDay, month, year;
        String[] split;
        if (args.length > 1) {
            split = args;
        } else {
            split = args[0].split("/");
        }

        theDay = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        System.out.println(theDay + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    }
```